# Create a basic email with setPayload for Gmail API

Tags: php, gmail-api

I am trying to send an email through the GMAIL api using PHP. The documentation is very scarce and really doesn't help beyond just getting emails. First, is there a better place for documentation that explains in detail how to do many of the basics with the PHP library? Second, how is this not valid?

```php
public function createPayload(string $message, string $to, string $sender, string $subject): \Google_Service_Gmail_MessagePart
{
    $messagePart = new \Google_Service_Gmail_MessagePart();
    $body = new \Google_Service_Gmail_MessagePartBody($message);
    $body->setData(base64_encode($message));
    $messagePart->setBody($body);
    $messagePart->setMimeType('text/html');
    $messagePart->setHeaders([
        [
            'name' => 'Content-Type',
            'value' => 'text/html; charset=utf-8',
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'Content-Transfer-Encoding',
            'value' => 'quoted-printable'
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'to',
            'value' => $to,
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'from',
            'value' => $sender,
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'subject',
            'value' => 'Subject: =?utf-8?B?' . base64_encode($subject) . "?=",
        ],
    ]);
    return $messagePart;
}
```

Comment: It would have been helpful if you referenced the origin of the classes you are using here. They are not part of the PHP distribution.

Comment: And also what do you mean by its not valid? What is not valid? Whats the error?